# Move Semantics and R-Value References in C++ String Construction

Tags: string, optimization, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

Will C++11 move semantics and r-value references in argument string constructs such as

```
do_something_with_string(std::string("abc"))
```

assuming declaration for example

```
void do_something_with_string(const std::string &);
```

make it possible to prevent the redundant heap-copying of `"abc"`?

If so will it make use of the `const char` wrapper `boost::cref` in `boost::const_string` unneccesary?

Comment: "Will C++11 move semantics and r-value references (...)" Seems like you forgot about the r-value references in your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't move data like that. The reason `const_string` has that overload for `const char*` is because `const_string` is *const*. It is immutable by its design. Therefore, it can store constant strings which are also immutable by reference, like a `const char*`: a string literal.

`std::string` is not immutable. Even if you only hold it by `const&` for the entire duration of its life, it is still not an immutable string. Therefore, it must copy from a `const char*` into its own private buffer.